# Does NewsFeed web part works if my site host is on separate web application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, newsfeed

This is a test environment and I have two web application. One of the web application, my.contoso.com, has a site collection with My Site Host. The other web application, portal.contoso.com, has a team site.

My problem is when I add the web part, Newsfeed in the portal team site, it does not have a start conversation block
[image]

But if I create a team site in my.contoso.com, which have the my site host, the Newsfeed Web part works perfectly.

[image]

Is it possible to have Newsfeed work properly while having Team Site and My Site Host on separate web application?
Or it needs to be in same web application and different Site Collections?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can view the start a conversation block in a site page in the web application which different from my site host located in.

Whether there is some custom code which might influence the web part to display correctly.

Please add the newsfeed web part in other pages/sites and check again.